# How to include space in column header in Oracle BI Publisher?

Tags: xml, oracle, csv, obiee, bi-publisher

I'm not able to include spaces in column header names

I've tried specifying column name in SQL query and changing the display name in the Structure tab and both don't work. When I try to change the XML tag name it errors out (space is an invalid character)

Comment: Your title says 'space in column header', which should certainly be possible, but it looks like you are trying to get a space into the XML element name. This is against XML naming rules.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN NOT have a column header name starting with space(s), but you can add padding to it in the bi-publisher report layout. You should select your table column header that you want,choose Properties tab and on Appearance section click on padding button (small one on the right with 3 dots):
[image]

Increase the left padding number, click ok and the column heaader will be moved to the right:
[image]
Regards...

Answer (score 0):

i had to replace the report template with an eText template to specify the column names in an rtf file.